# Integrating payment gateway with wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to integrate payment gateway with wso2 api manager.I'm following  wso2 documentation. According to [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+HTTP+Redirection+for+Workflows) documentation  "If you need to redirect back to the API Manager, call the workflow call back service to complete the workflow. To invoke this service, set the callback URL and the workflow reference ID in the additional parameters"
what exactly is the call back url here. and how to make subscription complete after payment is successfull. i.e to call complete method??

Answer (score 0):

Callback URL is a link which will be invoked by API method after its work is done. Here callback url is the additional parameter according to the API documentation. You need to set this field with the page where you want to redirect your client after payment.

Comment: document says "call the workflow call back service to complete the workflow" i don't think it is the url where i need to redirect client after payment. I want to redirect him back to the api store